# Passing variable inside an onClick function written as a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm passing `videoURL` in the `showVideo()` function, which is the onClick function for the `<a>` element.

```
var title = 'Click Me';
var videoURL = 'http://testurl.test';

$('#files').append('<a href="#" onclick="showVideo(videoURL);">' + title + '</a>');
```

However, clicking the `<a>` does not work. It gives me an error that videoURL is undefined.

**Other Attempt (did not work as well):**
The error was expected ')'.

```
$('#files').append('<a href="#" onclick="showVideo(' + videoURL + ');">' + title + '</a>');
```

How do I properly encode the variable I'm passing?

Comment: your second approaach looks good, whats wrong with it ? what doesnt work ?

Comment: @johnSmith No it doesn't, because it's not in quotes.

Comment: create your html string outside the append().

Comment: hi @johnSmith , it gives me expected ')' error.

Comment: '<a href="#" onclick="showVideo(\"' + videoURL + '\");">' + title

Comment: @johnSmith no luck on that one either.

Comment: You got minus 1 from someone because it was a silly mistake and they marked it as not helpful or not enough research :D
Just FYI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var title = 'Click Me';
var videoURL = 'http://testurl.test';

showVideo = function (url) {
  console.log(url);
};

$('#files').append('<a href="#" onclick="showVideo(\'' + videoURL + '\');">' + title + '</a>');
```

Comment: To explain why this works, your previous code made a the function call look like this `showVideo(http://testurl.test)` which as you can see would fail because the string is not in quotes.  This one puts quotes in there for you and it would look like this `showVideo('http://testurl.test')`.  Though personally I don't see why John didn't use double quotes instead of escaped single quotes...